# Do the notations $\int_0^1 u(x) dx$ and $\int_{[0, 1]} u(x) dx$ have the same meaning?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, notation

I am reading a paper in which the author uses both the notation
$$\int_0^1 u(x) dx$$
and
$$\int_{[0, 1]} u(x) dx$$
to denote the integral of a measurable function $u:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

My question is: do the $2$ notations mean the same thing in general? If it is not the case, could you please explain in detail which is the difference?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: no, they doesn't have, in general, the same meaning. The first is generally used to define an integral (maybe improper) of Riemann, and the second a Lebesgue integral. When the integrand is Riemann integrable then they have the same meaning.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2081811/42969 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3822616/42969. Also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3339784/42969

Comment: The first one specifies an orientation (starting from 0 towards 1) while the second does not.